# Performance problems with list.phtml? May be configurable attributes?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, product-list, performance

we have created a store (Magento 1.9.0.1) and

```
have heavy performance problems with category-listing and detail-pages.
```

we use an layered navigation and swatches - so i think there must be a problem?

We have 90% of the products are configurable products with round about 1-6 simple products in every configurable. The configurable attribute is just 1 (size) - but the attribute-set is only one for all products. The attribute-set has about 40-50 attributes (some of them filterable).

If I check the profiler - the list.phtml has about 16 seconds to load. Shown are 12 products on the category-page.

Does anybody have an idea where i could optimize something?

Comment: Try using "default theme", I doubt it's theme.

Comment: You state that there is only 1 attribute set for all products. And this attribute set has only 50 attributes ? Is it correct ? If so, check the extensions, theme code or custom code. There must be something wrong there, not in Magento Default.

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest looking at the logic in the list.phtml around the isSaleable() check.

For configurables this check is slower because it has to check each of the options to see if any are available for sale. Try commenting out that block of code and then check the performance.

Given that the results of that show that is where the performance is lacking, a possible solution would be for you to modify your template to not include the buy buttons. This may not be practical.

Also, check you have cache enabled?